# Joda chronology with null fields on Android (using Proguard)

Tags: android, proguard, jodatime

I'm using joda-time's LocalDates on Android. When I shrink my app with Proguard, I see NullPointerException when I'm comparing LocalDates (i.e., using LocalDate.equals()).

I did some poking around and it looks like the problem comes down to the Chronology of the LocalDate having null fields, e.g., ISOChronology.year() returns null. This bit of code triggers a RuntimeException when shrunk with Proguard (but not when using unobfuscated code):

```
if (marketDay != null && marketDay.getChronology().year() == null) {
  throw new RuntimeException("fail " + marketDay.getChronology());
}
```

The Chronology instances in use are plain ISOChronology[UTC] instances.

I assume I'm missing some magical incantation from my Proguard config, but I don't understand joda well enough to figure it out. I'd prefer not to mark all of joda to "keep". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard prints out notes on two instances of Class.forName in the code. If the class names for Class.forName are read from an external file, you need to preserve the corresponding implementations:

```
-keep class * implements org.joda.time.tz.Provider
-keep class * implements org.joda.time.tz.NameProvider
```

I haven't checked if this fixes your exception.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still get the same exceptions with this.